# How to solve the paradox in the negation to definition of limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

While learning a proof of the statement "A continuous function on a closed bounded interval is uniformly continuous", I faced with a hypothesis that the book had considered.

(Proof by contradiction of convergence, i.e. negation to "for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N$ s.t. for all $n\ge N$, $|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|<\epsilon$") ... so there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|\ge \epsilon$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Why contradiction to the first statement is the second one? I mean, contradiction to the first statement should be "for some $\epsilon>0$ there never exists some $N$ s.t. for all $n\ge N$; how this is equivalent to the book's statement (the second one)? (especially why $n\in \mathbb N$?)

**EDIT** - According to @par's answer, The negation of the statement
$$
\forall\epsilon>0:\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\colon\forall n\geq N\colon\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
is
$$
\exists\epsilon>0\colon\forall N\in\mathbb{N}\colon\exists n\geq N\colon\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|\geq\epsilon.
$$

which I am convinced by the negation; but it is intrinsically inconsistent:

The negation means $\exists\epsilon>0\colon\exists n\geq 1 \ \text {and}\ \exists n\geq 2\ \text {and}\ \dots \colon\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|\geq\epsilon$. Considering them together (some kind of intersection) $\infty\ne n\in \emptyset$, so again $\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|<\epsilon$, even in negation! **Am I right?**

I would appreciate a clear explanation.

Comment: say your second statement happens for N=50.  reduce epsilon for the first 49 cases to make it true for all n.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence

$$\forall \epsilon >0\exists \delta>0 :\forall  |x-y|< \delta :|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon $$

Negation

$$\exists \epsilon>0 \forall \delta>0 : \exists |x-y|< \delta , |f(x)-f(y)|\geq \epsilon $$

consider $\delta = 1/n$

so you will find $x_n, y_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n|<1/n$ and $|f(x_n)- f(y_n)|>\epsilon$.

Since you are in a compact set, you can consider without loss of generality (suffices to take a subsequence) that $x_n \to x^*$ now $y_n \to x^*$ but the continuity in $x^*$ implies that
$$|f(x_n) - f(y_n)|\leq |f(x_n)- f(x^*)| + |f(x^*) - f(y_n)| \to 0 $$

this is a contradiction with the assumption $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| > \epsilon$

Comment: Is there a method/recipe to find a negation in general? or it comes by 'mathematician' thinking? I mean since there is $\forall$ in the statement, so in negation it must be and $\exists$ ...

Comment: The method is quite mechanical, as you yourself noted  $\forall x: P(x) $ in negation becomes $\exists x \sim P(x)$ $\exists  x: P(x) $  in negation becomes $\forall x \sim P(x)$. With some practice  you will do this better.

Answer (score 1):

> The interpretation is not correct. Instead of using the quantor $\forall$ and state
>
> \begin{align*}
> \exists\epsilon>0\colon\forall N\in\mathbb{N}\colon\exists n\geq N\colon\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> you could consider the *countably infinite* set of statements
>
> \begin{align*}
> \exists\epsilon>0\colon\exists n\geq 1\colon&\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\\
> \exists\epsilon>0\colon\exists n\geq 2\colon&\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\tag{2}\\
> \exists\epsilon>0\colon\exists n\geq 3\colon&\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\\
> &\ldots
> \end{align*}
>   which is logically equivalent with (1).

Informally the meaning of the quantor $\forall$ in (1) is *whenever* you take a value $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ there exists an $n$ fulfilling the corresponding statement in (2).

Answer (score 0):

The negation of the statement
$$
\forall\epsilon>0:\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\colon\forall n\geq N\colon\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
is
$$
\exists\epsilon>0\colon\forall N\in\mathbb{N}\colon\exists n\geq N\colon\left|f\left(u_{n}\right)-f\left(v_{n}\right)\right|\geq\epsilon.
$$
Certainly you are right in saying that it is not necessarily true
for all $n$.

Comment: I think the book made mistake by writing "$\forall N\in\mathbb{N}\colon\exists n\geq N$" equivalent to $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ (?) or is it really equivalent?!

Comment: I edited the question according to your answer. Thank you

Comment: Yes, the book made a mistake.   They are not equivalent.  For example, it might be that $f(u_n) - f(v_n) = 1$ for even $n$ and $0$ for odd $n$.  
Then with $\epsilon = 1$, $\forall N \in {\mathbb N}: \exists n \ge N: |f(u_n) - f(v_n)| \ge \epsilon$ is true, but the book's version with $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ is false.